# С помощью чего можно реализовать эффект «карточек» при скролле сайта?

Tags: css

https://biotech.artlife.ru/ на этом сайте, при скролле, секции как бы надвигаются друг на друга, как карточки. Не могу понять как сделать такой эффект? Может кто-то встречал реализацию на codepen или какие-то библиотеки есть. Подскажите пожалуйста.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поищите "js stack cards on scroll". Вариаций много. Один из примеров: https://codepen.io/akapowl/pen/bGjBEdO

Comment: Можно готовыми плагинами воспользоваться, функционал большой там, правда не всё бесплатно, но что вам нужно вроде как бесплатно - https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/gOgWELo  и  вот страница их - https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger